# Multiple System Libraries Xamarin.Android app

Tags: c#, xamarin, reference, xamarin.android

I'm building a Xamarin.Android app, but one of my methods uses another System Assembly library different from the Xamarin.Android Base Class Libraries. How do I use the System Assembly from the .Net Frameworks 4.5 package in the same project? Thanks in advance

Comment: What "System" library are you specifically talking about?

Comment: When editing references, I want to add System assembly from the .NET framework 4.5 package.

Comment: You can not mix and match System BCLs from different frameworks